# Editing stacktrace after instrumentation

Tags: java, jvmti

I have a javaagent that performs some code instrumentation.
That of course changes the stack trace for the user, whenever they perform:

```
new Exception().printStackTrace()
```

And it also affects other services Throwable.class provides:

```
getStackDepth()
getStackElement(int i)
```

Etc...

My instrumentation involves adding a new method in some cases. The method has a very unique prefix, and I would like to ignore it, if possible.

Is that in any way supported by JVMTI?

Or do I need to instrument all of the ways in which the actual java developer using the agent can get a stacktrace / stackelements / stackdepth / etc...

Answer (score -1):

First of all, which Java are you using?

Please, check this documentation about ...
[StackTrace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetStackTrace)
&
[GetMethodName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetMethodName)

and check if you could use this to see if the getMethodName returns the prefix you use

```
char * request = (*jvmti)->GetMethodName
    if (strstr(request, "PREFIX") != NULL) {
        // contains
    }
```

Comment: Java 8. Yes. It does use have the prefix.